# Is the copula function invariant only under deterministic monotonic transformation?

Tags: copula, transform, invariance, deterministic

I read about the following theorem (see Proposition 3 in the picture below) on the invariance of copula under monotonic transformation, my questions  is:

**1. Are the $T_i$ mentioned in the following proposition required to be deterministic?**

My guess is it has to be a deterministic transformation. The proof below seems to have used the fact that the transformation is deterministic. Intuitively, the reason is that suppose $X_1,X_2$ are independent, which implies that $F_{\mathbf{X}}(x_1,x_2)=C_\mathbf{X}(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2))$, where $F_i(\cdot)$ is the cdf of $X_i$, and the copula function $C_{\mathbf{X}}(,)$ inherits the independence relationship. Suppose we do the transformation $Y_1=T_1(X_1)=X_1+e_1$ and $Y_2=T_2(X_2)=X_2+e_2$ where $e_1,e_2$ are correlated random variables. Although  $T_1$ and $T_2$ are strictly increasing functions, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ will be correlated. As $G_{\mathbf{Y}}(Y_1,Y_2)=C_\mathbf{Y}(G_1(Y_1),G_2(Y_2))$, where $G_i(\cdot)$ is the cdf of $Y_i$, the copula function $C_\mathbf{Y}(,)$ will inherits the dependence between $Y_1,Y_2$ and thus cannot be the same as $C_\mathbf{X}(,)$.
[image]

Another related question is, **if we are allowed to do random transformation, what's the requirement on the random transformation in order to preserve this invariance property?**

Thanks!

Comment: In your reasoning, it is unclear that $G_1(Y_1)$ and $G_2(Y_2)$ are correlated. In the linear case taken as example, $G_i(Y_i)=F_i(X_i)$ for instance.

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry, I didn't get it. Why it's unclear that $G_1(Y_1)$ and $G_2(Y_2)$ in my example are correlated? Also, how can you set $G_i(Y_i)$ to equal to $F_i(X_i)$ in my example? Can you explain it a bit further? Thanks!